# last character is removing in htaccess 301 redirect

Tags: .htaccess

When i write `/aaa/bbb/xyz-12/` it redirects me to `/aaa/bbb/xyz-12.html` but when i write `/aaa/bbb/xyz-12` redirects me to `/aaa/bbb/xyz-1.html`
It removes last character or number.

My rewrite rule is :
      `RedirectMatch 301 ^/aaa/bbb/(.*)\/?[^(.html)]$ www.xyz.com/aaa/bbb/$1.html`

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is faulty. Use this rule:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(aaa/bbb/[^.]+?)/?$ /$1.html
```